# I am trying to fill in a form by using PHP Curl

Tags: php, forms, curl, post

I am working on a little project. For this project in need to fill in a form on a third party website. I tried it with my code showed below, can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong? I am trying it on this form:

```
        <form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
        <table width="450px">
        <tr>
         <td valign="top">
          <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
         </td>
         <td valign="top">
          <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="top">
          <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
         </td>
         <td valign="top">
          <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="top">
          <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
         </td>
         <td valign="top">
          <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
         </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
```

And this is my PHP code

```
$url = '[domain]';
$fields = array(
'lname' => urlencode($_POST['$last_name']),
'fname' => urlencode($_POST['$first_name']),
'title' => urlencode($_POST['$title']),
'company' => urlencode($_POST['$institution']),
'age' => urlencode($_POST['$age']),
'email' => urlencode($_POST['$email']),
'phone' => urlencode($_POST['$phone'])
);

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: is there are any error messages?

Comment: Why are you setting `CURLOPT_POST` to the number of fields? That just takes a boolean value.

Comment: @Adam no error messages

Comment: @iainn even its boolean as long as the number higher than 0 so it should work.

Answer (score 0):

try like that to see curl errors:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch)){
    echo 'Request Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}else var_dump($result);
```

also, consider using http_bulid_query instead of this mess.

```
$data = array(
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'baz' => 'boom',
    'cow' => 'milk',
    'php' => 'hypertext processor'
);

echo http_build_query($data) . "\n";
```

Comment: I tried, but when i excecute on my mac it only shows string(800) and the html code of the website.

Comment: use echo instead of var_dump, that means the request was sent.

Comment: No error at all.. I don't understand why it ain't working.

Comment: No error so it's working, you said it shows string 800 so the result is a string with 800 char strength.